# Difference between "get rid of" and "rid of"

Tags: word-choice, verbs

What is the difference between the two? Would the following sentence work with "get rid of"?

> We need to rid the world of hunger.

Comment: My guess is that rid X of Y is more formal and might be more characteristic of written English. Get rid of X is less formal. Not sure though.

Answer (score 5):

There is a grammatical difference between how you use the two.

When you use the verb *to rid*, you use it with an object (in your example *the world*). This is followed by the prepositional phrase *of hunger*. In this sentence, the object represents the place that you want to see *cleaned*.

On the other hand, *to get rid of* just has the *of hunger* without the direct object. You can often express the same meaning by adding the place after: "We need to get rid of hunger in the world".

Answer (score 1):

"We need to get the world rid of hunger" almost works for me

If *the world* is a direct object then it should follow the verb. In *get rid of* the verb is *get*.

Comment: I agree with "**almost** works for me"... Substitute "make" for "get", and "free" for "rid", and then that sentence is a bit less cringe-inducing: *We need to make the world free of (from?) hunger.*